# Creating and Exporting Porous structure (large number of spheres... and boolean operations)

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model and simulate a porous media in a flow simulation software.
While they have some simplified algorithms designed to simulate porous media they are not capable of running the transient study that I need.

I have been scripting my way through this in the API of my CAD software to no avail, this software is just not made to handle large boolean operations (i.e. subtracting a large number of randomly sized spheres from a disc).

So I am wondering if Blender could be more successful at handling large number of spheres?

Before I venture into figuring out the right workflow, I'd like to ask: how many spheres can blender manage before being overloaded? I need 100,000. And of course is there a size limit on exporting STL files?

This is basically what I need to do, but with a disc rather than a bigger sphere as container and of course with an actual subtraction.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gM8yEMFMjg

[image: edit: screen of the disc with 10K spheres subtracted from it (the rest 90K have not).]
edit: screen of the disc with 10K spheres subtracted from it (the rest 90K have not).

Comment: Can your hardware handle 100,000 spheres? Well, you can test it easily with a sphere (start low-poly!) and the 3 *Array* modifiers (100, 100 and 10 = 100,000 spheres). This will result in 4.2 million vertices with the default Icosphere. Add a *Boolean* modifier, switch the setting to *Fast*, then select the object and you will see...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or a sketch to your question? It's hard to understand what you are actually trying. How and where do you want to simulate it?

Comment: I've been thinking about creating a "3D texture" of tightly packed varying size spheres. One could then use geonodes to scale it up to adjust the maximum size of spheres, and then remove spheres below a given threshold… A cuboid boolean aligned to axes as a cutter could also allow to replace boolean with a more efficient algorithm…

Comment: I'll edit the post if needed. I was able to create the 100,000 spheres with no issue. Doing the boolean subtract is another story. I got 10,000 spheres subtracted. Doing them in batches of 5000 at a time (I created 20 collections of 5000 spheres). I tried to export the disc (object) with 10,000 spheres subtracted and no success so far. Solidworks doesn't like it at all. Meshlab was able to import as I had read that meshlab is a good intermediary between blender and solidworks. Not sure what format to export out of meshlab though.

Comment: @Blunder I had no issue with generating the 100,000 spheres. I went with roundcubes though as I figured the topology would be a better match to the thermal simulation I was planning on running.